# Understanding Flask app contexts and views(routes.py)

Tags: python, flask

Looking at Flask's app contexts, I see something I don't understand. Inside a routes.py view function, I tried printing out the `current_app`'s memory address and the top of `app_context` queue's memory address and they don't match. Isn't `current_app` supposed to be the top from the top app-context?

The function:

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    from flask import current_app, _app_ctx_stack
    print("current_app:({},0x{:X}) _app_ctx_stack.top.app({},0x{:X})".format(current_app, id(current_app), _app_ctx_stack.top.app, id(_app_ctx_stack.top.app)))
```

The output:

```
current_app:(<Flask 'pov'>,0x1078A9990) _app_ctx_stack.top.app(<Flask 'pov'>,0x106A7AFD0)
```

I'm trying to build an extension and following the docs, I'm supposed to modify the the `app_context` at the top of the stack, but if this isn't the `current_app`, what's the point?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see. Its proxied.

```
 print("current_app:({},0x{:X}) _get_current_object({},0x{:X}) _app_ctx_stack.top.app({},0x{:X})".format(current_app, id(current_app), current_app._get_current_object(), id(current_app._get_current_object()), _app_ctx_stack.top.app, id(_app_ctx_sta    ck.top.app)))
```

```
 current_app:(<Flask 'pov'>,0x10FCE7948) _get_current_object(<Flask 'pov'>,0x10EEB5FD0) _app_ctx_stack.top.app(<Flask 'pov'>,0x10EEB5FD0)
```